# Не проходят Unit-тесты для сортировки пузырьком массива в Java

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, пузырьковая-сортировка

Это код для сортировки:

```java
    public class Main {

    public  static String[] getResult(String array[]){
        int arr[] = new int[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i], 2);
        }

        String a;
        int b;
        for(int i = arr.length-1 ; i > 0 ; i--){
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                if(arr[j] < arr[j+1]){
                    b = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = b;
                    a = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j+1];
                    array[j+1] = a;
                }
        }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String array[] = {"11001000","100101", "100"};
        getResult(array);
    }
}
```

Ниже приведен код теста для него.

```java
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

    public class TestMain {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        String[] start = new String[]{"100","100101","11001000"};
        String[] expected_result = Main.getResult(start);
        String[] result = new String[]{"11001000","100101", "100"};
        Assertions.assertEquals(result,expected_result);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`assertEquals` проверяет равенство ссылок на массивы.
Вместо `assertEquals` используйте [`assertArrayEquals`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertArrayEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)).

```java
    @Test
    public void test1() {
        String[] start = new String[]{"100", "100101", "11001000"};
        String[] expected_result = temp.getResult(start);
        String[] result = new String[]{"11001000", "100101", "100"};
        assertArrayEquals(result, expected_result);
    }
```